# How to markdown multiline code blocks in VS Team Services

Tags: markdown, azure-devops

How can I write multi line code blocks in in VS team Services that maintains the new lines. For instance I have two lines of code like this.

```
line one
line two
```

But no matter what I try the result always renders in one line like this.

```
line one line two
```

I have tried following the guide lines [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/reference/markdown-guidance#).

I have tried before and after back quotes

````
```
line one
line two
```
````

four leading spaces

```
    line one
    line two
```

Leading & trailing empty lines, triple back quotes on every line, wrapping every line in back quotes, and several other options but the result is not what I want. Is there some trick to multi line markdown block quotes in VS Team Services to make this work?

Comment: I check it today, the issue has been fixed. What's your result now?

Comment: Yes, looks like it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same content/code works fine in dashboard and file explorer (Code > Files > Select README.MD) pages, but doesn’t work fine for project page. I submit a feedback here: [VSTS Markdown in project page multiple line of code issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/39478/vsts-markdown-in-project-page-multiple-line-of-cod.html), you can follow it.